# How to merge same Ids data with mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, group-by

I have records like this after applying joins

```
id   name   item
1    bil    Books
2    mike   Table
2    mike   chair
3    josh   pen
3    josh   pencil
4    peter  copy
```

But, I want them to look like this

```
id   name   item
1    bil    Books
2    mike   Table,chair
3    josh   pen, pencil
4    peter  copy
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `group by`  and `group_concat()`:

```
select id, name, group_concat(item) items
from mytable
group by id, name
```